# Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I want to convert a `java.util.Date` to `JodaTime` so as to carry out subtractions between dates. Is there a good concise way to convert from `Date` to `JodaTime`?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

```
java.util.Date date = ...
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
```

Make sure `date` isn't `null`, though, otherwise it acts like `new DateTime()` - I *really* don't like that.

Comment: So basically: `DateTime dateTime = date==null?null:new DateTime(date);`

Comment: +1 for "otherwise it acts like new DateTime() - I really don't like that."

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Old thread but don't you mean  DateTime dateTime = date ==null ? new DateTime() : new DateTime(date); ? Just wondering... tx

Comment: @BabajidePrince No; then you would get the same value as new DateTime(null), which is exactly what we wanted to avoid.  The expression is meant to maintain null as null, which is what makes sense in most situations.

Comment: Be aware that Java Date is TimeZone independent while Joda DateTime has a Chronology.

Comment: Yes, a time or two the if null act like new DateTime() is caused me a bit of anoyingness...

Comment: Generally better to specify a time zone rather than rely on implicit default. If you omit a time zone, the JVM's default time zone is assigned to new DateTime object. I suggest this… `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );`. Or, for UTC use the constant… `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC );`

Comment: I just got bitten with the passing null behaviour and remembered seeing this.

Answer (score 15):

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

Each datetime class provides a variety of constructors. These include the Object constructor. This allows you to construct, for example, DateTime from the following objects:

```
* Date - a JDK instant
* Calendar - a JDK calendar
* String - in ISO8601 format
* Long - in milliseconds
* any Joda-Time datetime class
```

Comment: @skaffman if you wanted to avoid null dates you could use date.getTime() instead.  You would be getting a null pointer exception however that may be better than silently failing.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't just overloaded their constructor for those objects.

Comment: @PieterDeBie - because the system is generic. You can register your own object types to have conversion to or from.