# How can I convert java.util.Date to org.joda.time.DateTime?

Tags: datetime, date, vaadin

I have to use java.util.Date class as field type in a table.
But I would like to change the display format of the date field with help of joda time (confortable, prefered to use), thats why I want to convert a Date to DateTime.

I know I oversee something, because there is no such a question in stackoverflow :) but I could not find the soulution among the DateTime constructors and so on.
The reverse conversion *DateTime.toDate();* 
exists, but what about the opposite way ?

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Cs

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks, but according to the api there is no such a constructor which accepts Date ... Thanks again, maybe I misundertood something.

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin, if you want to change display format in a table without joda, you simply override the method `protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId,
                    Property property)`

Here an example to do it :

```
Table t = new Table() {

        @Override
        protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId,
                Property property) {
            Object v = property.getValue();
            if (v instanceof Date) {
                Date dateValue = (Date) v;
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd").format(dateValue);
            }
            return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
        }

    };
```

Regards

Éric

Comment: Thanks Eric, but so many people prise jodatime thats why I would like to get to know it a bit. But I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, Use Joda-Time

Definitely use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). The old [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and outmoded.

Also, read the Wikipedia pages on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

## Yes, Pass Date To Joda-Time Constructor

➔ Yes indeed, you *can* pass a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object to the [constructor](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(java.lang.Object,%20org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) of a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

The API doc is a bit confusing as this apparently falls into the catch-all version of the constructor taking an [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) instance. If that Object is in fact a `java.util.Date`, Joda-Time will extract its millisecond-count-since-[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) and use that number as its own.

## Time Zone

A `DateTime` constructor also assigns a time zone. By default, the JVM’s current default time zone is assigned. I recommend you *always* pass a desired time zone rather than rely implicitly on the default even if that means calling `getDefault`.

## Example Code

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.5 showing how to pass a java.util.Date to a Joda-Time constructor.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTimeMontreal = new DateTime( date , zone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeMontreal.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Adjust to another time zone.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "date: " + date ); // Misleading output. A j.u.Date is in UTC but its toString method applies JVM’s current default time zone.
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontreal: " + dateTimeMontreal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run.

```
date: Sat Oct 18 18:54:55 PDT 2014
dateTimeMontreal: 2014-10-18T21:54:55.740-04:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-10-19T01:54:55.740Z
```

As shown in the Question, to go from a DateTime to java.util.Date, call `toDate`.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTimeMontreal.toDate();
```