# Joda: Convert Date and Time to DateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, jodatime

Is there a way to convert a Time and Date variable to a DateTime?

I have a period between two DateTime variables, for each Date in that period I want to store a period IN that Date with a begin DateTime and end DateTime, so a day can have multiple periods defined by a DateTime.

Can't seem to figure out how to combine Date and Time to a DateTime.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "a Time and Date variable"? It would be much easier if you would show us code rather than describing it.

Comment: java.sql.Time beginTime and java.sql.Date beginDate, I want to form a dateTime from them

Comment: Luc -  give us an example of what you want to do. makes things clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it using this:

```
public DateTime dateAndTimeToDateTime(java.sql.Date date, java.sql.Time time) {
    String myDate = date + " " + time;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    try {
        utilDate = sdf.parse(myDate);
    } catch (ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(utilDate);

    return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Plain java `Date` and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) should serve the purpose.

```
Date date = new Date(); // java.util.Date; - This date has both the date and time in it already.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
```

For more [info](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) about Joda-Time.

If you have two `String` objects, where 1 holds the `Date` and the other `Time`, you can combine the 2 Strings and use a [SDF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse it and get the `Date` object, which you can then convert to `DateTime`.

Comment: Regarding that last paragraph… If you include a `T` between that date and time ([standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), you can pass the string directly to a constructor of [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). No need to use the SimpleDateFormat & Date classes. Just a single line of code. Like this… `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2013-01-02T03:04:05", DateTimeZone.UTC );`

Answer (score 3):

Even if this question is a bit older and already answered, I could not find a satisfying solution. The best method for this problem is probably the following code (without any parsing and exception handling required):

```
public DateTime dateAndTimeToDateTime(java.sql.Date date, java.sql.Time time) {
    DateTime t = new DateTime(time);
    return new DateTime(date).withTime(t.getHourOfDay(), t.getMinuteOfHour(), t.getSecondOfMinute(), t.getMillisOfSecond());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that you can find how to construct date and time instances separately.

However on the datetime object itself you can specify the following.

```
dateTimeObject = dateTimeObject.withHourOfDay(12);
dateTimeObject = dateTimeObject.withMinuteofHour(59);
dateTimeObject = dateTimeObject.withSecondOfMinute(59);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

With java.time, the modern Java date and time API, this is simple and straightforward:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(23, 45);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.NOVEMBER, 23);

    LocalDateTime combined = date.atTime(time);
    System.out.println(combined);
```

Output is:

> 2019-11-23T23:45

I know you asked about Joda-Time. However, the Joda-Time homepage says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Joda-Time homepage](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("yyyy-MM-dd");.

System.out.println("============> " + dateTime.toString());
```

**INPUT** :  2018-01-04
**OUTPUT**: ============> 2018-01-05T00:00:00.000+05:30

Comment: It doesn’t seem to answer the question? I read it as a question of combining date *and time* .