# JodaTime PeriodFormatter

Tags: jodatime, period, periodformatter

I have the following PeriodFormatter:

```
PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
        .appendMinutes().rejectSignedValues(false).maximumParsedDigits(2).toFormatter();
```

and if I parse e.g. **-03:00** (three hours):

```
final Duration hoursDuration = periodFormatter.parsePeriod(hours)
```

but if I parse e.g. **-00:43** (45 minutes) than I get a positiv duration because the right format would be **-00:-43**.

My question now would be it there is a possibility with **periodFormatter**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime)

Comment: Duplicate??? How is `PeriodFormatter` related to `java.util.Date`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First I make your code compilable:**

```
PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = 
    new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
    .appendMinutes().rejectSignedValues(false).maximumParsedDigits(2).toFormatter();
Period p1 = periodFormatter.parsePeriod("-03:00"); // PT-3H
System.out.println(p1);
Period p2 = periodFormatter.parsePeriod("-00:43"); // PT43M
System.out.println(p2);
```

**Explanation for the observed behaviour:**

Joda-Time handles the signs of any period in a counter-intuitive way since the very beginning. **Signs** are never **related** to the whole period but only to the **single distinct components of a period**.

- First case "-03:00" => Only the hour component is negative (and minutes are zero).
- Second case "00:43" => The hour component is zero so the sign has no effect while the minute component is positive because it is not directly preceded by a negative sign.

The opinions about this behaviour are in dissent. While the Joda-team seems to consider this as enhancement and useful feature other people like me find it terrible. For example, it is possible to construct a period as P1M-30D. Is such a period positive, negative or zero? We don't really know. And the result is that a period looses the property to be like the length of a directed vector on the timeline (what is characteristic for a duration).

As far as I know there is no chance to change this behaviour in Joda-Time. **If you want to parse "-00:43" as -PT43M** then consider following options:

**a) Manual workaround:**

```
String input = "-00:43";
boolean negative = input.charAt(0) == '-';
Period p3 = periodFormatter.parsePeriod(input.replace("-", ""));
if (negative) {
    p3 = p3.negated();
}
System.out.println(p3); // PT-43M
```

**b) Using my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J):**

This is rather a cannon for solving your concrete problem but otherwise it is worth a look because the possibilities to normalize, format or parse any duration are overwhelming. Time4J rejects mixed signs so the sign can only be in front of the whole duration.

```
Duration<ClockUnit> d = Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "-hh:mm").parse(input);
System.out.println(d); // -PT43M
```