# Converting Instant Time into Joda Time in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clj-time

I am stuck trying to convert an #inst "2016-08-15T14:00:00.000-00:00" into #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x1d4c2099 "2016-08-15T20:47:52.658Z"].

I am trying to do this in order to add (t/minutes duration) to my time/date!

Is there a way to convert the instant into joda time in clojure?

Comment: Also, is there a way to parse only the time from an instant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `(clj-time.coerce/to-date-time my-inst)` will do the trick?
the coerce namespace has a bunch of helpers for moving between types.